# Getting wrong backgroud image from live URL in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am trying to get image from URL which has transparent background.

But whenever I try to use it with NSData, I am getting a black background instead.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
NSData *imgageURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Image URL"]]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageURL];

[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Here in button image, I got a black background instead of transparent.

How do I get transparent image from URL to work?

Comment: Have you tried using buttonWithType = UIButtonTypeRoundedRect

Comment: @azamsharp ,YEs but still getting black background of image

Comment: Try using setBackgroundImage:im

Comment: It will be easier to answer if you provide full URL of test image.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the image has really transparent background (please you provide image url). Is it PNG image?

Second, check what color is the background of button's superview (and it's superviews), you can set it to **[UIColor clearColor]**

Hope it helps

Comment: yes,I have transparent PNG image.And Also try to set image in temporary ImageView..but still get Black background

Answer (score 0):

Try using setBackgroundImage:buttonImage instead of setImage.

Comment: Then also get black backgound to image

Comment: Please provide the image link!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
NSData *imgageURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Image URL"]]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageURL];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

there is only problem of background color.

or open the receiving image in photoshop.